# Test Class for updating count on another Object using Aggregate

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

The code is working fine and covering only 54%. My test Class could not covering AggregateResult (Bold Part)

```
trigger DrawingSharing on Drawing__c (after insert, after update) { 
    if(trigger.isInsert){ 
        List<Drawing__c> lstDrawing = new List<Drawing__c>();
        for (Drawing__c eachDrawing : Trigger.new){
            lstDrawing.add(eachDrawing);
        }
        //<---------------Creating Installation Record with each Installation Activity added on Drawing--------------------->
        List<Installation__c> lstInstalltion = new List <Installation__c>();
        for(Drawing__c eachDrawing :lstDrawing){
            for(String installationActivityList :eachDrawing.Installation_Activity__c.split(';')){
                if(installationActivityList != null){
                    Installation__c inst = new Installation__c();
                    inst.Drawing_ID__c = eachDrawing.Id;
                    inst.Installation_Activity__c=installationActivityList;
                    inst.Execution__c=eachDrawing.Execution_ID__c;
                    inst.Floor__c=eachDrawing.Floors__c;
                    lstInstalltion.add(inst);
                }
            }
        }
       
        if(lstInstalltion.size() > 0){
            insert lstInstalltion;   
        }
         //<-----------Sharing Of Access on Drawing Records ------------------------->
        Map <Id,Id> DrawingProjectMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        Map<Id,Drawing__c> drawingIdObjMap = new Map<Id,Drawing__c>([select id, name,Approver__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c from Drawing__c where id in :lstDrawing]);
        for(Drawing__c Drawing : drawingIdObjMap.values())
        { 
            DrawingProjectMap.put(Drawing.Id,Drawing.Execution_ID__r.Project__c);
            system.debug('Drawing' + Drawing);
        }
        system.debug(DrawingProjectMap);
        system.debug('drawingIdObjMap.keyset()'+ drawingIdObjMap.keyset());
        system.debug('drawingIdObjMap.values()'+ drawingIdObjMap.values());
        
        Map<Id,RoleObjectSharing__mdt> roleobjaccessmap = new Map<Id,RoleObjectSharing__mdt>([select id,Object__c,role__c,Accesslevel__c from RoleObjectSharing__mdt where Object__c='Drawing']);
        Map<String,String> RoleAccessmap = new Map<String,String>(); 
        for(RoleObjectSharing__mdt Robj : roleobjaccessmap.values()){
            RoleAccessmap.put(Robj.role__c,Robj.Accesslevel__c);   
        }
        system.debug(RoleAccessmap.keySet());
        system.debug(DrawingProjectMap.values());           
        Map<Id,Projects__c> teamrolemap = new Map<Id,Projects__c>([select Id,(select id, User_Lookup__c,Role__c from TeamRoles__r where Role__c in:RoleAccessmap.keySet()) from Projects__c where Id in :DrawingProjectMap.values()]);
        system.debug('teamrolemap'+teamrolemap);
        List <Drawing__Share> DrawShareList = new List<Drawing__Share>();
        INTEGER countFound = 0;
        for(Drawing__c drawobj : lstDrawing){                                                         
            Projects__c proj = teamrolemap.get(DrawingProjectMap.get(drawobj.id));
            system.debug(proj.teamroles__r);
            for(teamroles__c tr : proj.teamroles__r){
                system.debug(tr);
                if(tr.Role__c == 'PlanningEngineer' || tr.Role__c == 'AssistantPlanningEngineer' || tr.Role__c == 'PlanningManager' || tr.Role__c == 'AssistantPlanningManager' && countFound <=0) {
                    countFound = countFound + 1;
                    Drawing__c ddd = drawingIdObjMap.get(drawobj.Id);
                    ddd.Approver__c = tr.User_Lookup__c;
                    update ddd;
                }     
                Drawing__Share recruiterShr = new Drawing__Share();
                recruiterShr.ParentId = drawobj.Id;   
                recruiterShr.UserOrGroupId = tr.User_Lookup__c;
                recruiterShr.AccessLevel = RoleAccessmap.get(tr.role__c);
                recruiterShr.RowCause = tr.role__c+'__c';
                DrawShareList.add(recruiterShr);
            }
            system.debug(DrawShareList);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(DrawShareList,false);
        Integer i=0;
        for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
            if(!sr.isSuccess()){     
            }
            i++;
        } 
     
     //<----------------- Updates of Counts on Execution and Projects ------------------------------->
    ***if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){ 
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw1 = new List<Execution__c>();
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw2 = new List<Execution__c>();
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw3 = new List<Execution__c>();
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw4 = new List<Execution__c>();
        
        List<Projects__c> updateProjectsDraw1 = new List<Projects__c>();
        List<Projects__c> updateProjectsDraw2 = new List<Projects__c>();
        
        
        
        //<------------ Update Number of Shop Drawing Quantified on Execution from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Shop_Quantification_Completed__c = true GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawing_Quantified__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawing_Quantified__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw1.add(updateMe);
        }
        
        **//<------------ Update Number of GFC Drawing Quantified on Execution from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE GFC_Quantification_Completed__c = true GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_GFC_Drawing_Quantified__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_GFC_Drawing_Quantified__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw2.add(updateMe);
        }
        
          //<------------ Update Number of As Built Drawings Approved on Execution & Project from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE As_built_Drawing_Client_Approval_Status__c IN ('Approved', 'Approved with Comments') GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c  HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_As_Built_Drawings_Approved__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_As_Built_Drawings_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw3.add(updateMe);
           
            Projects__c updateProj = new Projects__c();
            updateProj.Id = (String)count1.get('Project__c');
            updateProj.As_Built_Drawing_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateProjectsDraw1.add(updateProj);
        }
        
        //<------------ Update Shop Drawing Approved on Execution & Project from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Shop_Drawing_Client_Approval_Status__c IN ('Approved', 'Approved with Comments') GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c  HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawings_Approved__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawings_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw4.add(updateMe);
            
            Projects__c updateProj = new Projects__c();
            updateProj.Id = (String)count1.get('Project__c');
            updateProj.Shop_Drawing_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateProjectsDraw2.add(updateProj);
        }
        
        update updateExecutionDraw1;
        update updateExecutionDraw2;
        update updateExecutionDraw3;
        update updateExecutionDraw4;
        update updateProjectsDraw1;
        update updateProjectsDraw2;
    }
}*****
}
```

Test Class:

```
static testMethod void Test4001(){  
        System.debug('TestSharing = Test4001'); 
        
        Projects__c proj = new Projects__c();
        proj.Name = 'Hello';
        proj.LL_Location__c='Mumbai';
        insert proj;
        
        TeamRoles__c tr = new TeamRoles__c();
        tr.User_Lookup__c = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        tr.Role__c = 'PlanningEngineer';
        tr.Project_Name__c = proj.Id;
        insert tr;
        
        Execution__c ex = new Execution__c();
        ex.Project__c = proj.Id;
        insert ex;
        
        Item_Master__c ItemeMaster = new Item_Master__c();
        ItemeMaster.Item_Description__c = 'testing';
        ItemeMaster.Item_Code__c = 'testing';
        insert ItemeMaster;
        
        Project_Items__c projItems = new Project_Items__c();
        projItems.Total_PO_Quantity__c = 0;
        projItems.ItemMaster__c = ItemeMaster.Id;
        projItems.Execution__c = ex.Id;
        insert projItems;
        
        Test.startTest(); 
        Drawing__c draw = new Drawing__c();
        draw.Execution_Id__c = ex.Id; 
        draw.Floors__c  = '3F'; 
        draw.Installation_Activity__c='Cable Tray';
        draw.As_built_Drawing_Client_Approval_Status__c = 'Approved';
        draw.As_Built_Marked_Drawing_URL__c = 'http:\\www.google.com';
        draw.Received_Marked_Drawing_Hard_Copies__c = True;
        draw.Marked_Drawing_Photos_URL__c = 'http:\\www.google.com'; 
        draw.Prepared_Title_Sheet__c = True;
        draw.Removed_Legend_Quantity_from_As_built_Dr__c = True;
        draw.Prepared_As_Built_Drw_Based_on_Marked_Dr__c = True;
        draw.Submitted_As_built_Drawing_for_Approval__c = True;
        draw.As_Built_Marked_Drawing_URL__c = 'http:\\www.google.com';
        insert draw;
        draw.Shop_Quantification_Completed__c = true;
        draw.GFC_Quantification_Completed__c = true;
        draw.Shop_Drawing_Client_Approval_Status__c = 'Approved';
        Drawing__c CheckDrawing = [SELECT Execution_Id__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Id =: draw.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, CheckDrawing);  
        System.assertEquals(draw.Execution_Id__c, CheckDrawing.Execution_Id__c); 

        Drawing_Line_Items__c dll = new Drawing_Line_Items__c();
        dll.Drawing_Number__c = draw.Id;
        dll.Project_Items__c = projItems.Id;
        dll.Project_Name__c = proj.Id;
        dll.Installation_Activity__c='Cable Tray';
        dll.GFC_Quantity__c = 15;
        dll.Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c = 20;
        dll.GFC_Drawing_Line_Item_Done__c = true;
        dll.Shop_Drawing_Line_Item_Done__c=true;
        insert dll;
       
        
        // Class not Trigger
        List<Drawing__c> listProj = CircularProgressController.getDrawing(draw.Id);
        
        
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you edited out all your code? As is, there's no information to act on in this question and it's likely to be closed.

Comment: I got the best way to do the code and find my code as a waste of time for others also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the very simplest of classes, your test class should have more than one test method.

Code coverage is the metric that Salesforce enforces (because that's realistically the only thing they *can* enforce). As developers though, the point of testing is to give us confidence that our code isn't broken and that it behaves as expected under a wide range of scenarios. By testing a wide range of scenarios, you'll naturally attain high code coverage.

You ideally want each test method to only focus on one thing. You also want to only assert against a few things at a time too. If you have one monolithic test, you'll only be able to know about one issue at a time. If you spread the work over many tests, you can get a better picture of your code as a whole and it'll help narrow down problematic sections.

You want to test "negative cases" too, things like "my code depends on the record I give it having a child record. What happens if it doesn't have a child record?"

Assertions are also *vital to unit testing*. Assertions are what makes tests useful to us. Assertions are what you use to verify that the output, the result of running your code, matches what you expect it to be. If you're inserting a new SObject record, assert that you have one more record after running your code compared to before it was run (run a query before, and a query after). If your code returns a List of something or other, assert that the list isn't empty, assert that it contains the number of objects you expect, etc...

With that out of the way, here's the main issue...
**You only get coverage for code that is executed as part of running your tests**.

The code you point out as being uncovered is in a block that only runs after update of a `Drawing__c`. Where in your test are you updating a `Drawing__c`? Given what you've shared so far, there is no update.

No update = update portion of your trigger is not run = no code coverage for that part.

#### Bonus

Your "after update" block is horribly wasteful (and not bulkified, given that your queries are only driven by `trigger.new[0]`). You don't need four separate updates here.

Instead, you should use a `Map<Id, Execution__c>` to track and re-use object instances. Something like

```java
Map<Id, Execution__c> executionMap = new Map<Id, Execution__c>();

for(<your query>){
    // Since we'll be using this Id more than once, it'll save us some
    //   typing to make it a variable
    Id targetId = (Id)result.get('your id');

    // In English, if the Id doesn't exist in the map, put it into the map
    if(!executionMap.containsKey(targetId){
        // The SObject constructor can take fieldName/value pairs
        // It's fast to execute, and also saves us some typing
        executionMap.put(targetId, new Execution__c(Id = targetId));
    }

    // Non-primitive types (i.e. things that aren't Integer, String, Boolean, etc...)
    //   are stored in collections as _references_
    // So if we .get() an SObject from a map, and then make changes to it, the
    //   changes are also made to the record in the map (no need to .put() again)
    Execution__c targetRec = executionMap.get(targetId);
    targetRec.Field = value;
    targetRec.Field2 = value2;
}

// basically repeat for your other loops

// Then do a single update (instead of 4)
update executionMap.values();
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarity on the code, but I am updating same aggregation part in 2 different object using same aggregation. That's why I have written 4 different updation.

Comment: @apz You have 6 total update DML statements at the end (4 on one object, 2 on the other). That can (and should) be reduced to a total of 2 updates by making use of maps (one map per object). It also might be possible to reduce the number of queries you're using, but I didn't look into them quite that far.